# List not being sorted by BubbleSort

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, bubble-sort

Have a bubblesort program that I would like emails to be sorted into alphabetical order. However when I run the program with the List I would like to be sorted I get the error TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.
Here is the code:

```
def BubbleSort(logindata):
    NoSwaps = 1
    N = len(logindata)
    while NoSwaps == 1:
        Count = 1
        NoSwaps = 0
        for Count in range(N-1):
            if logindata[Count] > logindata[Count+1]:
                temp = logindata[Count]
                logindata[Count] = logindata[Count+1]
                logindata[Count+1]=temp
                NoSwaps=1
    return logindata

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logindata=["tom@gmail.com","Password1"],["Harry","Password2"],["Jake","Password3"]
    BubbleSort(logindata)
    print(logindata)
```

The program sorts a list without the 'Passwords'. How would I get the code to run and successfully sort it.

Comment: you are not capturing the return value from the `BubbleSort` function. Capture the return value and print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With assuming that your Bubble sort algorithm works correctly , Your problem is you can not assign item in `tuple` , when try `logindata[count] = logindata[count+1]` , you can change `logindata` to `list` then return the `tuple` of `logindata` ,and also you should capture returned `logindata` and then print it,the whole code looks like this:

```
def BubbleSort(logindata):
    NoSwaps = 1
    N = len(logindata)
    logindata = list(logindata)
    while NoSwaps == 1:
        Count = 1
        NoSwaps = 0
        for Count in range(N-1):
            if logindata[Count] > logindata[Count+1]:
                temp = logindata[Count]
                logindata[Count] = logindata[Count+1]
                logindata[Count+1]=temp
                NoSwaps=1
    return tuple(logindata)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logindata=["tom@gmail.com","Password1"],["Harry","Password2"],["Jake","Password3"]
    logindata = BubbleSort(logindata)
    print(logindata)
    #(['Harry', 'Password2'], ['Jake', 'Password3'], ['tom@gmail.com', 'Password1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will run and sort the list. However I don't know if this is the way you want to do it.

```
def BubbleSort(logindata):
    NoSwaps = 1
    N = len(logindata)

    while NoSwaps == 1:
        Count = 1
        NoSwaps = 0

        for Count in range(N-1):
            if logindata[Count][0] > logindata[Count+1][0]:
                temp = logindata[Count][0]
                logindata[Count][0] = logindata[Count+1][0]
                logindata[Count+1][0] =temp
                NoSwaps=1
                temp = logindata[Count][1]
                logindata[Count][1] = logindata[Count+1][1]
                logindata[Count+1][1] =temp
    return logindata

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logindata=["Adam","Password1"],["Harry","Password2"],["Cake","Password3"]
    BubbleSort(logindata)
    print(logindata)
```